# How can I copy a database schema from my local Sql Server to Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, ssms, azure-sql-database

I figured the way to do this was to go to my existing database (Sql Server 16.0.1105.1 developer edition) in SSMS and run Tasks | Generate Scripts...

[image]

This includes a FullTextTable. So I then got the following script (just showing the start):

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [LouisHowe]    Script Date: 11/15/2023 5:56:31 PM ******/
CREATE DATABASE [LouisHowe]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'LouisHowe', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\LouisHowe.mdf' , SIZE = 73728KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'LouisHowe_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\LouisHowe_log.ldf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 WITH CATALOG_COLLATION = DATABASE_DEFAULT, LEDGER = OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [LouisHowe] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 160
GO
IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
EXEC [LouisHowe].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
end
GO
ALTER DATABASE [LouisHowe] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF
```

And it seems to have created the database ok. But I got close to 200 error messages (showing just the first few):

```
Msg 40508, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different database.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 'ON'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
Msg 5011, Level 14, State 5, Line 12
User does not have permission to alter database 'LouisHowe', the database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows access checks.
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
```

What do I need to do to fix the script?

Comment: _What do I need to do to fix the script?_ -- Remove or modify all statements that are not supported Azure SQL Database. Better yet, use the [tool Microsoft provides for your use case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/migration-guides/database/sql-server-to-sql-database-guide?view=azuresql).

Comment: @mustaccio Is there no simple way to get a generic works on any SQL Server script? I like the idea of having a script as a backup. TIA

Comment: @DavidThielen "*Is there no simple way to get a generic works on any SQL Server script?*" - Azure SQL Database is a completely different database than SQL Server. Not all features that SQL Server has are available in other database systems, such as Azure SQL Database. It's not SQL Server's job to keep track of which of its own features are not available in other database systems. So it's not possible to do what you want via the `Generate Scripts` methodology in SSMS, which is just using SQL Server's system objects to get the scripts from.

Comment: @J.D. Ok, thanks. What would be optimum is if Entity Framework would generate scripts for a specified database. Unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: @DavidThielen Best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mustaccio mentioned in the comments, it would be easier to just use the tools that Microsoft provides.

The [Azure Migrate tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/migrate/azure-migration-guide/), which can be added from the marketplace, has been getting better and better and makes copying your data to the cloud quite easy, this is quite a big tool and is perhaps a bit much for your needs.

A different but very easy to use tool is the [Azure Data Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-ver16).
This tool can do an assessment, which checks if you have features on premise that you cannot migrate to your cloud target (Or any other target/version) afterwards it can also do the final migration for you. For an Azure SQL Database it will basically do what you're trying to do, create a script and run it on the target.

There are [more tools/options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/migration-guides/database/sql-server-to-sql-database-guide?view=azuresql) to migrate to the cloud as well if you want to find more options.